# Problems after upgrading adt plugin to 23.0.6.1720515 and sdk tools to 24.1.2

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I recently upgraded the Adt plugin to 23.0.6.1720515 and sdk tools to 24.1.2. and sdk to 5.1. Each time I try to create a new project I get the following error `ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing`. Is there any solution or workaround? Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a new eclipse project? I did notice the 'eclipse' tag but please confirm

Comment: Yes, When I try to create a new eclipse project I get the above error. The older projects have no problems.

Comment: Another problem has turned up. The older projects are not displaying the designers. I get the following error - Exception raised during rendering: Unable to find the layout for Action Bar.
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: Getting the same problem, the workaround I used was setting the target of the application to be Android 4.4 :/

Comment: Yes! setting the target to 4.4 seems to work.

Comment: the solution is here.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535863/exception-raised-during-rendering-unable-to-find-the-layout-for-action-bar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535863/exception-raised-during-rendering-unable-to-find-the-layout-for-action-bar

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. Make sure you have installed the latest `Android SDK Build-tools`. Then restart `Eclipse` and re-import projects.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to down grade the API level of target preview device.Click the android robot icon select appropriate level.