# Exception raised during rendering: Unable to find the layout for Action Bar

Tags: android, android-studio

While using Android Studio just now I was editing an XML file in the editor and I got this error in the Preview and Design windows:

```
 Exception raised during rendering: Unable to find the layout for Action Bar.
```

I've tried restarting Android Studio, my Laptop and Googling for the answer but I can't find anything. Has anybody experienced anything similar?

Comment: are you using a custom view or something "unusual" in your xml

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I had this kind of error. On My Mac, there is API 22. If I choose it this error will appear. So clicking on API 21 or below would solve your problem

[image]

You probably need to update your tools

Comment: This error kept coming to me until I checked also "Automatically Pick Best".

Comment: Thanks for letting us know @Andre! This is only a temporary solution but will find a way to use API 22. I'll update the answer once I go back to work.

Comment: My experience: I had "Automatically Pick Best" and was getting there error. Switching to "19" caused the problem to go away for me.

Comment: yeah, you right, change from 22 to 21 in graphic layout to fix this problem

Answer (score 14):

Those using Eclipse might try to choose Theme.DeviceDefault to eliminate the exception.
Update: as per comments this works for Android Studio also.
[image]

Comment: This works for Android Studio 2.2 also. This was the solution for me.

Comment: as this works for android studio also (solved my problem) please update answer and put android studio near eclipse

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this problem by two ways

> Change API from the tab, Try one of them from the available or Select PICK UP BEST or change your minimum sdk

[image: Select API from the available]

> Change the Theme if first solution not work

[image]

Comment: For me the solution was to go Device Default -> device default

Answer (score 2):

Click on Theme in Editor and change the theme:

[image: click on theme in editor and change the theme]

MY issue is solved after this

Comment: @DimaSan : What a remarkable change you have made to increase points

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on eclipse-3.8, adt-23.07, sdk-tools-23.1, appcompat_v7_r19.1.

After analyzing the error I found the problem is in
android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/data/layoutlib.jar:com/android/layoutlib/bridge/impl/Layout.class on method `createActionBar` at line `if (this.mBuilder.isThemeAppCompat())`

My solution:

1. (don't have the source, so) decompile Layout.class -> Layout.java
2. edit Layout.java, add method:

```
    private boolean hasWindowDecorActionBar(SessionParams params) {
        LayoutlibCallback callback = params.getLayoutlibCallback();
        try {
            callback.findClass("android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ei) {
            try {
                callback.findClass("android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

3. Locate the line `if (this.mBuilder.isThemeAppCompat())` then change to :

```
    if (this.mBuilder.isThemeAppCompat() && hasWindowDecorActionBar(params))
```

4. recompile Layout.java -> Layout.class and Layout$Builder.class
5. update layoutlib.jar with the new classes
6. restart eclipse

That's all. Now, I can render using API-23 all of my old app layouts that links against appcompat_v7_r19.1.

Answer (score 0):

You suppose to do clean project.

Answer (score -1):

i think it is a bug and there is no ultimate solution until this moment,
changing to API less than API-22 is a temp solution not more.